# EHF peppol 3.0 invoice for norway government

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, invoice, xml-schema-collection, ubl

I am trying to generate xml file for the invoice which has to submitted in the form xml file EHF peppol 3.O, I unable to find the exact xml schema for this anybody can help me on this

Comment: A full year has passed, and my answer is still not accepted. Do you find it to be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

EHF Billing 3.0 is based on UBL 2.1, just like PEPPOL BIS Billing 3.0 and EN16931.

There is documentation at https://anskaffelser.dev/postaward/g3/spec/current/billing-3.0/

Comment: could you please elaborate? I need this for a project I'm working on with .NET framework. Are there any APIs to be used for this solution?